# What is hashCode used for?

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time figuring this out. What is hashCode as I never fully understood it.

Example:

```
  int m = 2;
  int b = "APA".hashCode() % 3000;
  int v = "KLK".hashCode() % 3000;
  for (int x = 0; x <= v; x++)
     m = (m ^ x) % b;
  return m;
```

What is the return value? Maybe this will make me fully understand hashCode.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()

Comment: For storing an object in a Map, and for a first pass at an equality check

Comment: What is the return value though?

Comment: If you really want to understand what a hash code is for, please look up "hash table" in Wikipedia (it talks about a "hash function", which is what `hashCode` is).  If you think that knowing that the result is 1955 helps you understand what `hashCode` is all about, then I have no idea what you're looking for.

Comment: correction: `hashCode` isn't the hash function itself; rather, the hash function is the hash code modulo the table size.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[hashcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29) used in computer science to create a nearly O(1) access to object with hashmaps and hashtables, hashcode can be md5,sha1 or any other encryption.

the return value in this case is 1955

Comment: Do you know the return value of integer m?

Comment: the return value is 1955, you could just run it

Comment: Thanks, lol, now I finally get it.

Comment: Hashing is not encryption.

Answer (score 0):

> A hash code is a just a "value". A hashcode method just takes an
>   object and outputs a numeric value. The hashcode for an object is
>   always the same if the object doesn't change.
>
> So using this knowledge, you can use hashCode for many things, for
>   example for a HashMap. In HashMap you want to find a matching key
>   quickly when you do a lookup. So you first check the requested key's
>   hash code, and then you can really efficiently find all the keys in
>   your map with that hash code. You can then check each of those (and
>   only those) candidate keys for equality against the requested key.